# Using certutil to check certificate responses

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509

I am having a lot of trouble setting up an X509 certificate scheme in C#.NET.  SSL is enabled on the server and the connection is being made over SSL.  Certificates are being added to the request's store via `request.ClientCertificates.Add()`.  However, no client certificate is being attached to the handshake request (which I am both confirming by both checking the server's code through `HttpRequest.ClientCertificate` and by analyzing the handshake in Fiddler).

As nearly as I can tell, the problem here is that the server is not requesting a client certificate.  The certificates are definitely in the outgoing request, but I see none on the handshake and none on the server side - they simply disappear into the ether.  I'm aware of the semantics behind choosing a certificate (thanks to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229719.aspx)), but it hasn't resolved my problem.  The CAs should be the same; I am using the same self-signed, private key secured certificate for each end of the test.

Apparantly I can use certutil.exe to check which certificates will be chosen when used with a given server certificate.  This would be a huge help if I could figure out how to use it like this.  Certutil is a big program that is poorly documented.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS serverside you MUST provide certificate that is trusted by your server. So you MUST add client cert' CA cert into server computer 'Root certificate authorities' storage. IIS doesnt work with self-signed certificates. It requests client cert providing list of CAs it trusts to.